# Gunicorn with 1 Worker works faster that Uvicorn for FastAPI app on single-core k8s Pod

Tags: python, fastapi, performance-testing, gunicorn, uvicorn

I run my FastAPI application (Python 3.11.5) through the Gunicorn with 1 worker,  using UvicornWorker class.
My Deployment in k8s contains 2 Pods with only 1 CPU-core for each. I thought about using the Uvicorn directly because I cannot take the multi-cores advantages in accordance with the CPU limits and it seemed like I don't need the Gunicorn at all.
But when I tried to run my app through the Uvicorn, I saw that on 50+ RPS the service's performance became worse than with Gunicorn (Prometheus is used for collecting metrics)

I assume that when using Uvicorn there is only one Process to serve incoming requests, while using Gunicorn with 1 worker there are 2 Processes: main process and worker process.

But, anyway, I don't fully get how (even if my assumption is correct) the Gunicorn can work better in my case (1 CPU-core Pods)

Comment: What kind of workload are you using for testing? What's the task that the server should perform?

Comment: The service handles the incoming request from the User and then it makes predictions based on the User's data received, (this is a CPU-bound stuff, which is run within the separate thread). The performance tests emulate some amount of Users sending their requests and this amount is increased on the different stages.

Comment: Then I would guess, without seeing the code, that the CPU bound tasks are better handled with threads from `gunicorn`, since it was born when `async` was not used

Comment: For the running CPU-bound task in separate thread I use concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor which is set to the event loop within the application's lifespan.Technically this model is the same for gunicorn as well as for the uvicorn. The only difference I see that the gunicorn uses at least 2 processes while the uvicorn uses the only one

Comment: Probably the performance difference lies in the number of threads and the approach they take with threads. `guinicorn` was developed for exploiting a multithreaded environment, while `uvicorn` was developed for exploiting one thread but `aynsc`. That's the explanation I can come up with.
Edit: probably, the context switch between threads for k8 is better than for the async one

Comment: With a cpu bound, when you run by gunicorn without `--threads`, it means your fastapi application will proccess `1 request` by one time. Every resource only processes one request until it is finished before processing it again, that avoid for switching another `thread` by many requests. when you use uvicorn directly, all request will be handle by many thread tasks and switch between threads while needing to handle only task for fast. You can apply `--threads` with high value, maybe 200 and check throughput

Comment: I think the amount of threads would be helpful using multi-core machine and using language another than GIL'ed Python :( The general question was occurred by itself, because it's very strange behaviour that is still unclear for me, but, anyway, thank you, guys, for the ideas!